# Show $\mathbb {P}(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}Z_n/\ln n=1)=1$ for $Z_n$ iid $Exp(1)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> $\mathbb {P}(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}Z_n/\ln n=1)=1$ for $Z_n$ iid $Exp(1)$

I guess I have to use Borel-Cantelli but I am struggling with especially one part.
Shouldn't we have

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \{Z_n/\ln n=1\} = 0 < \infty$ as $Z_n$ are continues Random Variables?

Comment: Indeed, use Borel-Cantelli with the events $$A_n^x=\{Z_n>x\ln n\}$$ for various values of $x$.

Comment: @Did So $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \mathbb {P}(A_n^x)\begin{cases}
= \infty,  & \text{if $x \le$1} \\
< \infty, & \text{if $x >1$}
\end{cases}$ and I can use Borel Cantelli but how do I get the final result from there?

Comment: You first: which conclusion(s) do you get using BC?

Comment: @Did For $x \le 1$: $\mathbb{P}((\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}Z_n/\ln n>x)=1$ 

For $x >  1$: $\mathbb{P}((\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}Z_n/\ln n>x)=0$ 

From the first I can conclude that $\mathbb{P}((\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}Z_n/\ln n \le x)=1$  for $x\le 1$ and thus we have  $\mathbb {P}(\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}Z_n/\ln n \le 1)=1$

but how can I get to other inequality?

Comment: Well, you know that $$\limsup Z_n/\ln n>x$$ almost surely for every $x<1$ and that $$\limsup Z_n/\ln n<x$$ almost surely for every $x>1$, hence $$\bigcap_k\{\limsup Z_n/\ln n>1-\tfrac1k\}\cap\{\limsup Z_n/\ln n<1+\tfrac1k\}$$ has probability $1$. Now, this event is $____$ hence you are done.

Comment: Finally understood it, thank you!